# Issue with Phonegap / Cordova and Android dev

Tags: android, cordova, command-line

I started learning Phonegap and cross-platform mobile dev. I have an issue testing my Android app while only using command line.

Windows 7, Nexus 5 linked to the computer and found in the adb devices.

So, building a new Phonegap project, adding Android to it with no problem.

```
phonegap build android
```

works fine. Then :

```
c:\Android\Project\hello>phonegap install android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] no device was found
```

Device is properly linked with usb debugging checked. What's "amusing" (but not really for me right now) is that if I launch Eclipse, adds the project and run it as an Android project, it uploads and launch on my device instantly. The point is, I don't want to launch Eclipse just for that...

Please help me resolve this.

BTW I also tested the emulator on Eclipse, it's awfully slow ! Isn't there a better way to test this, or the only option is to have my phone linked all the time ?

Comment: Well, I found the solution quite fast after asking, even if I was stuck for a long time before... The problem was I had another app with same name on my phone. Removing it solved the problem, it worked perfectly. Still needing help for my second question though !

Comment: I also just found this thing : http://emulate.phonegap.com/ that gives the ability to test directly in an emulator inside a Chrome extension. Would you guys recommend using something like this ?